# How to automatically convert custom-formatted string to DateTime when reading data by OLEDB from excel file?

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, oledb

I'm using OLEDB to read Excel spreadsheet.

```
<add key="Data.Source.Connection.String"
      value="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=[DATA_SOURCE];Extended Properties=&quot;Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;&quot;" />
```

I have a custom formatting "hhmm" which appears to be a military time string on the spreadsheet but a date in the Formula Bar.

One particular column gets detected as `DateTime` very well... the other always detects as a `string` into which I am having to parse manually. When attempting to create the new `DateTime` object I encounter this error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
```

I have working version of the fix, however I am curious as to what makes the C# `dynamic` type detect `DateTime` on one column and `string` on the other. In Excel they look the same as far as formatting goes.

The `value` variable is a C# dynamic type. The current code I am using to fix this:

```
if( !DBNull.Value.Equals( value ) ) {
    try {
        entity.Attributes.Add( "actual_time",
            Convert.ToDateTime( value ).ToUniversalTime() );
    } catch( Exception ) {
        // In case date comes across as string.
        DateTime actualTime = entity.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>(
            "actual_time" );

        int hours = Convert.ToInt32( value.ToString().Substring( 0, 2 ) );
        int minutes = Convert.ToInt32( value.ToString().Substring( 2, 2 ) );

        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan( hours, minutes, 0 );

        actualTime = actualTime.Date + ts;

        entity.Attributes.Add( "actual_time", actualTime );
    } // catch
} // if
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please create a [MCVE] that demonstrates your problem? As such, it is really hard to understand what is going on.

Comment: *"In Excel they look the same as far as formatting goes"* Try looking at the raw column data (in a text viewer, not Excel). You will probably see what the difference is.

Comment: @SonerGönül I have updated what I have to fix. I am only curious why the same custom formatting from Excel would detect as `DateTime` on one column and as `string` on another.

Comment: @RonBeyer In Notepad++, they both show as `string`s.

Comment: always hard-code columns as your required types when you read data from file. all persited data are always strings, whatever types were shown in Excel or Notepad, they are the types by their logics, but now you need your own logic to render all strings to your types, like render `int` numbers to `Enum`

Comment: @Dongdong Interesting you should say. It triggered a thought about using `cast (MyColumn as datetime)` or `cdate(MyColumn)`. Wondering what would happen if it was already a datetime if it would complain. Must try.

Comment: Read your post twice again, I believe what your question is: How to automatically convert a string column which has this format `hhmm` to `DateTime`? is it correct?

Comment: @Dongdong It already happens properly on one column but on another column in the same spreadsheet a `string` is detected instead of `DateTime`. I already checked to see if the columns are the same custom format in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Find Excel-SQL syntax from here: [Writing SQL Queries against Excel files (Excel SQL)](https://querysurge.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205766136-Writing-SQL-Queries-against-Excel-files-Excel-SQL-), which is pretty simple to apply on your code.

If your excel is solid-formatted(or generated), use `type conversion` functions:

```
SELECT CDATE(DATETIMECOLUMN) AS DATETIMECOLUMN FROM SOMESHEET$
```

If above sql is not good enough for your case, try `8. Date formatting` from above link.

```
SELECT FORMATDATETIME( [SALE_DATE], 1),   --read above link for number meanings
      FORMAT([ACTUAL_DATE], 'yyyy-mm-dd')
FROM [SALES$]
```

You can also use `IIF(IsNull(column),'default value',column)` to handle `null` values.

If your excel could be edited manually, formats are not solid, I would read all data as `string`, but parse them with C# logic.

```
SELECT CSTR(DATETIMECOLUMN) AS DATETIMECOLUMN FROM SOMESHEET$
```

Comment: Thanks for your responses! I will give this a try later today. Hopefully the results are consistent.